# How to create a function that will split continuous variables only to groups equal size groups

Tags: r, dataframe

I would like to run a function over my data frame that will find only continuous variables and add new categorial variables based on dividing the continuous variables to 2 equal size groups. I have a code that I use to split a variable to groups and add it as anew categorial variable but when I tried to use it in a function it does't work.What could be the problem? Also, how can I avoid from running over non continuous variables?
Here is a toy data frame:

```
df <- read.table(text = "         birds    wolfs     
                                    9         7    
                                    8         4    
                                    2         8    
                                    2         3    
                                    8         3    
                                    1         2    
                                    7         1    
                                    1         5    
                                    9         7    
                                    8         7     ",header = TRUE)
```

my function is:

```
for (i in names(df)) function (x) { as.factor( as.numeric( cut(df$i,2)))  }
```

Comment: Perhaps `df[paste0(names(df), 'new')] <- lapply(df, function(x) factor(cut(x, 2, labels=FALSE)))`

Comment: Thanks @ akrun, what should I do in order to evoid non continuous variables? also, what is wrong with my function, am I missing somthing?

Comment: In your function, you are using `df$i`.  I would use `df[,i]`.  Second, the output needs to be stored in another object or so.  It is not defined.

Comment: For example `lst <- vector('list', ncol(df)); for(i in seq_along(df)) {lst[[i]] <- as.factor(as.numeric(cut(df[,i], 2)))}`

Comment: Thanks a lot @akrun..I appreciate your help.

Comment: You should be able to skip non-numeric variables like this: `df[paste0(names(df), 'new')] <- lapply(df[,sapply(names(df), function(x) is.numeric(df[,x]))], function(x) factor(cut(x, 2, labels=FALSE)))`.

Comment: However if I use the is.numeric function I may get binary variables as well.

Comment: Try `lapply(df1, function(x) !all(x %in% 0:1) & is.numeric(x))`

Comment: You should be able to narrow the set further by adding conditions to that function in the call to `sapply`. So, to exclude binary variables as well, use `sapply(names(df), function(x) is.numeric(df[,x]) & !all(df[,x] %in% 0:1))`.

Comment: Thank you guys , your comments will help me with a lot of other issues..

Comment: @akrun, yeah, your last comment posted while I was testing my suggestion, and I didn't see yours until I'd added mine.

Comment: sure.. thanks a lot..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are some possible problems in your function

```
for (i in names(df)) function (x) { as.factor( as.numeric( cut(df$i,2)))  }
```

1. I would use `df[,i]` to subset the column instead of `df$i` as it is not evaluated properly
2. There is no need for the anonymous function call `function(x)`.
3. Output is not stored in another variable.

The first two can be easily fixed.  We create an empty `list` object with `length` equal to the number of columns of 'df' (`ncol(df)`).  This can be used for storing the results ('lst')

```
lst <- vector('list', ncol(df))
```

Now, we loop through the columns of 'df' (assuming that all the columns are numeric) and apply the `cut` function to each of the columns (`cut(df[,i],..`).

```
for(i in seq_along(df)) {
        lst[[i]] <- as.factor(as.numeric(cut(df[,i], 2)))
 }
```

We can assign new columns with the output of 'lst'

```
df[paste0(names(df), 'new')] <- lst
```

Another option instead of `for` loop would be `lapply`.  The results from the `lapply` can be directly assigned to new columns.

```
df[paste0(names(df), 'new')] <- lapply(df, function(x)
                   factor(cut(x, 2, labels=FALSE)))
```

---

Based on the OP's comments about filtering the `numeric` columns alone (even excluding the binary columns) for applying the `cut`.  We create a logical index with `vapply`.  It loops through the columns of 'df2' and check whether it is 'numeric' (`is.numeric(x)`) and if it contains values other than 0, 1 (`!all(x %in% 0:1)`).

```
 indx <- vapply(df2, function(x) !all(x %in% 0:1) & is.numeric(x), logical(1L))
```

Using the same code as above including the 'indx' vector

```
   lst <- vector('list', ncol(df2[indx]))
   for(i in seq_along(df2[indx])) {
       lst[[i]] <- as.factor(as.numeric(cut(df2[indx][,i], 2)))
    }
  df2[paste0(names(df2)[indx], 'new')] <- lst
```

Or with `lapply`

```
 df2[paste0(names(df2)[indx], 'new')] <- lapply(df2[indx],
                  function(x) factor(cut(x, 2, labels=FALSE)))
```

#### data

```
set.seed(24)
df1 <- data.frame(col1=sample(0:1, 10, replace=TRUE),
           col2=rnorm(10), col3=letters[1:10])
#df - OP's dataset

df2 <- cbind(df1, df)
```